# How can I remove all files from current directory using terminal?

Tags: command-line, delete

I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I tried `rm 'ls'`, `rm rf` but they did not work.

Comment: **WARNING OF DELETION** 

For just deletion of files on current directory: `rm ./*`
 and For deletion of files and folders inside in is `rm -R ./*` if you want no prompt mode, there is always `-f` parameter for that

Answer (score 83):

Use `rm *` from within the specific directory. The `*` is a wildcard that matches all files.

It will not remove subdirectories or files inside them. If you want that too, use `rm -r *` instead.

**But be careful! `rm` deletes, it does not move to trash!**

To be sure you delete the right files, you can use the interactive mode and it will ask for confirmation on every file with `rm -i *`

Comment: * doesn't match hidden files. You'll need to explicitly reference `.*` for those.

Comment: If you want to remove both visible and hidden files and folders you can call: `rm -r * .*`

Answer (score 27):

`rm *` will, by default, delete all files with names that don't begin with `.`. To delete *all* files and subdirectories from a directory, either enable the bash `dotglob` option so that `*` matches filenames beginning with `.`:

```
shopt -s dotglob
rm -r *
```

(The `-r` flag is needed to delete subdirectories and their contents as well.)

Or use `find`:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -delete
# or
find . -mindepth 1 -exec rm -r -- {} +
```

The `-mindepth 1` option is to leave the directory itself alone.

Comment: Let's say i'm emptying a Trash folder. Would "find . -mindepth 1 -delete" follow symlinks, thus delete things in external folders?

Comment: `rm -fr * .*` does the job as well. `.*` does not match `..` or `.`, to be safe.

Comment: I never tried this, but [Filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html#Filename-Expansion) allows regexes, thus excluding the `..` reference: `rm -rf * .[^.]*` but this still omits unusual filenames beginning with 2 or more dots such as `..foobar`.

Comment: @eelghEEz Filename expansion most definitely does not allow regexes - it does have similarities in the syntax, but not in the semantics. Extended globbing does have regular semantics, but doesn't match the syntax.

Comment: @ArtemRussakovskii -- depends on your shell. for instance, bash excludes `.` and `..` but `sh` includes them.  but, TIL bash does not.